# mysql cross-updating a table

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to solve this problem.
I have a table (A) I need to update, with a structure like this:

```
CODE    VALUE
1       a
2       null
3       null
etc...
```

Then I have another table (B) with the same structure but with every value set:

```
CODE    VALUE
1       a
2       b
3       c
```

What I need to do is to copy data from table B to table A where A.CODE = B.CODE but only if A.VALUE is not set.
What's the best query to do so? Can't do it by hand since I'm dealing with 2000ish rows.

I wrote something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
update A set VALUE = 
    (select b.VALUEfrom B b, A a where b.CODE = a.CODE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE a SET a.Value = b.Value
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON (a.CODE = b.CODE)
WHERE a.VALUE IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE a.VALUE IS NULL`

Comment: I think so as well. I'm checking both answers a bit before accepting one.

Comment: @Ic - Good spot - my bad and corrected. I think the difference between the 2 answers is that the join above avoid the sub query and should be more efficient and easier to read. Depends on data and testing of course.

Comment: Thank you bhs, I think I'm going to upvote both questions. Probably won't pick one since yours is more clear but @HampusNilsson's follows my boss's code style and both are correct.

Comment: Maybe you could educate your boss ;-)

Comment: Tell me how to do that without being fired :D

Comment: I'd be tempted to just do it as above - if he's a good manager he should recognise that you've both learned something. If not .... Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check that a.VALUE is set to do the update, and only select from the B table in the inner clause (and use the value of A from the outer clause):

```
update A
  set VALUE = (select B.VALUE from B where B.CODE = A.CODE)
  where VALUE IS NULL;
```

Comment: This seems to work. But I have another problem: some lines are just empty and I can't replace them. I tried using `where VALUE = ''` but it gives me an error: subquery returns more than one row. I'm stuck here.

Comment: I added a `limit 1` inside the inner clause and that solved the problem. Probably a duplicate line?